# Release different version of single app on google play store for specific country in Production track

Tags: android

**Release different versions of a single app on the google play store for the specific countries in the Production track**

For Example 1.0.0.x released on 40 countries 100% rollout

Now I have release 2.0.0.x which I release in Only 12 countries out of 40 countries with stage rollout.

Now I have release 3.0.0.x which I want to release this only 10 Countries of 12 countries of release 2.0.0.x. If we do that using stage rollout then 2.0.0.x will be removed from play store. But we want to keep the 2.0.0.x remaining 2 countries.

Anyone has an idea please help to achieve this in the Google play store or is there any other way we can achieve this.

Let me know required more information

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your circumstances you could think about implementing feature toggles. Then you can enable or disable specific features based on the location the user is in. However, this needs some infrastructure and careful planning. Have a look at https://eng.uber.com/piranha/

Comment: Hi @Bennik2000 we can not release the application even if the feature is disabled and the code is there. Because when we update the version number then we need to certified that new build in that country. 

so we need to release a specific feature build to a specific country.